# How to activate iptables on Debian 7?

Tags: iptables

I think I've asked iptables to drop any packet for the port 8091, but the tcp connection still succeeds.

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
$ iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination     

$ telnet localhost 8091
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain.
Escape character is '^]'.
(That means the TCP connection is established, despite the iptables rule)
```

Does that mean iptables is inactive? Do I have to 'apply' the rules or is iptables deactivated by default on Debian?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're setting the iptables rule on interface eth0, but telnetting to localhost, which is interface lo and therefore ignored by your iptables rules.

Try telnetting to the ip address of eth0 and see if you get the same result

Comment: Even if you didn't set the eth0 predicate there are certain chains loopbacks skip.  I forget if input is one of them though.

Comment: Hi jerm, I've tried with the IP address too (the one of eth0=142.4.202..., not 127.0.0.1 obviously) and it was the same result.

Comment: Try telneting from another host and make sure you're making the connection via eth0 not some other interface.

Comment: Telneting to the address on eth0 from the local host is still via the `lo` interface as far as the kernel is concerned. You need to test from a remote host as @Matt has said.

Comment: You were right: I was using the lo interface. The glitch was, I couldn't test from another physical machine because of firewall restrictions (I'm using a VPS), and now that I can, the ports are open/closed as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your config should work.  I duplicated it myself, and found that while I could still access the port from the server itself, access from outside was blocked.

Try to telnet from another location.